# google plus signinbutton inside a fragment shows null pointerexception onclick

Tags: java, android, facebook, google-plus

I want to login to my app through googleplus and facebook. I am getting null pointer exception. I searched and tried all the possible ways.
I do not know what is wrong with code. Please help me with this.

This is MainActivity.java

```
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;

 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;
import com.saloon.callbacks.LoadProfileImage;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MapFragment()).commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class MapFragment extends Fragment implements    View.OnClickListener,
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener
{   private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    // Google client to communicate with Google
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private boolean signedInUser;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private SignInButton signinButton;
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView username, emailLabel;
    private LinearLayout profileFrame, signinFrame;

    private AccessTokenTracker tracker;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    MapFragment(){


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            eventListeners();

     }

    private void eventListeners() {

         signinButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
            AccessToken access= result.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                  displayPage(profile); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Login Cancel", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),  error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                 
            }

        };
        tracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {

            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldone,
                    AccessToken newone) {

            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {

            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile,
                    Profile newProfile) {

            }
        };

        tracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();

        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    //  initializer();
        signinButton = (SignInButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.signin);
        image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        username = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        emailLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);

        profileFrame = (LinearLayout)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.profileFrame);
        signinFrame = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.signinFrame);

         mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(rootView.getContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
        return rootView;


     }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == MapFragment.RC_SIGN_IN){
         if (resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
             signedInUser = false;
            }

        mIntentInProgress = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayPage(profile);
    }

private void displayPage(Profile profile) {

        if(profile!= null){
            Intent intent = new   Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

public void logout(View v) {
    googlePlusLogout();
}   

private void googlePlusLogout() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateProfile(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        tracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), getActivity(), 0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // store mConnectionResult
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (signedInUser) {
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        signedInUser = false;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getProfileInformation();
    }

    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String email =  Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                username.setText(personName);
                emailLabel.setText(email);

                new LoadProfileImage(image).execute(personPhotoUrl);

                // update profile frame with new info about Google Account
                // profile
                updateProfile(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updateProfile(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            signinFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            profileFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            signinFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profileFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateProfile(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.signin:
            googlePlusLogin();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void googlePlusLogin() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            signedInUser = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    public void signIn(View v) {
        googlePlusLogin();
    }

}
}
```

And i am getting this exception:

```
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.saloon.myapp/com.saloon.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
 08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
08-12 11:54:10.541: E/AndroidRuntime(23032): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in `onCreate` of Fragment

```
eventListeners();
```

and then

```
 private void eventListeners() {

     signinButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Your singinButton needs to be initialized before that

Look at the Fragment lifecycle here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Its onAttach, onCreate and then onCreateView..... Your button is initialized in onCreateView.

NPE can also occur if you reference the wrong id from xml. But in your case you have set Button click listener in onCreate while you initialize button in onCreateView

Comment: @MD where?? in `onCreateView`. initialize before use

Answer (score 2):

You should move

```
 signinButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

inside `onCreateView(.....)` becoz `signinButton=null` at

```
 signinButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```